# How to set cookie under my firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

How to set cookie under my firefox addon?

```
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
        ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires : "") +
        ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
        ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
        ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
}
setCookie("foo", "bar");
```

This simple js is not set cookie in firefox addon, but in web-page work well.

Answer (score 4):

From the add-on you can use the cookie manager XPCOM:

```
    var ios = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
    var cookieUri = ios.newURI("http://www.yourplacewhereyouwanttosetthecookie.com/", null, null);
    var cookieSvc = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/cookieService;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsICookieService);

    cookieSvc.setCookieString(cookieUri, null, "your_key=your_value;", null);
```

You can find more details here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Cookies#Setting_a_cookie

Comment: This code seems to not work in Firefox 4. Are there any changes regarding cookie service in FF4/Fennec?

Comment: In addition, the flag HttpOnly doesn't work when using that functionnality.